# Ruby - How to test for nil or empty string from console(stdin)

Tags: ruby, oop, conceptual

I'm very new to ruby so please bear with me... In a text on Ruby there is a code example that does this:

```
str = gets
exit if str.nil? || str.empty?
str.chomp!
temp, scale = str.split(" ")
```

My queries are as follows:

Given that `gets` will only return up to and including the `cr` why test for the empty string?

If you test the following:

```
puts nil.to_s.empty?
puts "".to_s.empty?
puts "".length            #the empty string      : equates to 0
puts nil.to_s.length      #the 'to string' method: equates to 0
```

Both will evaluate to true and have zero length. However, the only thing in the stream, if there is only a `cr`, is the ***carriage return*** itself. `str` will have a length of 1 in the following if you just hit the enter key.

```
print "enter a string or hit the enter key : "
str = gets
puts str.length
puts str
```

Furthermore, `nil` in ruby is an ***object***. How the heck am I suppose to capture **that** from `stdin`?

I now see that the `chomp!` is misplaced within the text, the author's mistake **not** mine:

```
str = gets
str.chomp!
exit if str.nil? || str.empty? #test for zero length string will now work
temp, scale = str.split(" ")
```

Granted, I come from java and *some* common lisp and therefore may be too antiquated to grok this, but I still don't see how the test for `nil` is appropriate in this context. Maybe there are some conceptual differences in streams that are further along than my reading. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

To clear up some confusion here is the code re-written with only the change to placement of the `chomp!` statement:

```
#temperature-converter.rb
#code changed by poster, otherwise as written by author
print "Please enter a temperature and scale (C or F) : "
STDOUT.flush   #self explanatory....
str = gets
str.chomp!     #new placement of method call -- edit by poster
exit if str.nil? || str.empty?
#chomp! original position -- by author
temp, scale = str.split(" ")
abort "#{temp} is not a valid number." if temp !~ /-?\d+/
temp = temp.to_f
case scale
    when "C", "c"
        f = 1.8 * temp + 32
    when "F", "f"
        c = (5.0/9.0) * (temp - 32)
else
abort "Must specify C or F."
end
if f.nil?
    puts "#{c} degrees C"
else
    puts "#{f} degrees F"
end
```

And the output:

```
=>ruby temperature-converter.rb
Please enter a temperature and scale (C or F) : 30 c
86.0 degrees F
=>ruby temperature-converter.rb
Please enter a temperature and scale (C or F) : j c
j is not a valid number.
=>ruby temperature-converter.rb
Please enter a temperature and scale (C or F) : 30 p
Must specify C or F.
=>ruby temperature-converter.rb
Please enter a temperature and scale (C or F) :    #just the enter key
=>                                                 #did this just exit?!
```

but the answer selected by me is correct, if you use Ctl+D(U) or Ctl+Z(W)
eof can be emulated and a `in '<main>': undefined method 'chomp!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` is error is thrown. Still, the string is never empty so checking the condition doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), `gets` can return a string or `nil` :

> Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the list of files in
>   ARGV (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the
>   command line. Returns nil at end of file.

## From Standard input

see @MarkoAvlijaš' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013795/ruby-how-to-test-for-nil-or-empty-string-from-consolestdin/42013930#42013930) with CTRL+D.

## From ARGV

You can create an empty file called `empty.txt`, and launch :

```
ruby your_script.rb empty.txt
```

Nothing should happen.

If you remove the second line though :

```
your_script.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `chomp!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I don't see how `str` could be empty with the above code. At the very least, there will be a newline if `str` isn't `nil`.

Note that if you use `chomp!` before checking that `str` isn't `nil`, you might get a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Thanks, after reading the doc's provided I checked and your assessment was correct. Ciao.

Comment: You're welcome. Credits go to Marko for finding about CTRL+D

Answer (score 1):

**`gets` can return nil if you press CTRL+D** (at least in irb)

CTRL+D is unix signal which means I am done typing or end of file.

That's why code in the book is correct. Your version will produce `NoMethodError` in that case.

```
gets.chomp!
NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp!' for nil:NilClass
```

That's why he is first testing for `nil`, then calling `chomp!`

Look into edit history of this answer if you want more newbie friendly tips. I have removed them because they are not relevant to this answer.

Comment: Nice find for `Ctrl+D`. I don't understand your point with `chomp!` though.

Comment: Look at the end of his post where he posts code as he thinks it should have been. It's basically `gets.chomp!`

Comment: Yes. I don't see how `chomp!` possibly returning `nil` is relevant.